# Error console in Mozilla shows a cache.html which is not readable

Tags: java

Error console in Mozilla shows a `cache.html` which is not readable. How can I make it readable?

Comment: It seems you are including or making `GET` to `cache.html` but its on server not readable . any code or some useful things needed to answer

Comment: My servlet throwing an error which is written to the response. And the respective form submit complete action will show a dailog box based on the rsponse

Comment: In the Development mode its happening as  expected but the build mode IE is saying some error thrown but not caught

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reasons are that the cache.html file does not exist, or that your web page or javascript is using the wrong URL to refer to it.

Comment: How else can i make out what error is being thrown and from  where

Comment: Error: uncaught exception: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): c is undefined
 stack: Hjh((void 0),"MainEntryPoint","CustomerRegistration")@http://10.105.142.75:8080/2CC8DCC5BC4F2268DA817978439144F2.cache.html:3701
cJg([object Object],[object Object])@http://10.105.142.75:8080/2CC8DCC5BC4F2268DA817978439144F2.cache.html:4882
DJg([object Object])@http://10.105.142.75:8080/2CC8DCC5BC4F2268DA817978439144F2.cache.html:2210

Comment: If you tagged your question correctly (this is a "javascript" / "gwt" problem) and put the details in the question, someone might help.  Edit your question, to include the above details, and stuff like the Java and Javascript code that is causing the problem.